# jQuery Validate not working on URL with double quotes

Tags: jquery, regex, json, jquery-validate

jQuery Validate plugin doesn't seem to validate a URL with double quotes, such as this:

```
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=3x3&iu=/xxxxxxx/xxxx_xxxxx&ciu_szs&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url="+ document.referrer + "&description_url=xxx.xxx&correlator=" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

It will, however, validate up to the first double quote. Since I am looping through my form field names, how can I apply a regex to the field before it is looped through to escape the `"`. Or is there a better way with the jQuery Validate plugin?

Original URL:

```
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=3x3&iu=/xxxxxxx/xxxx_XXX_xxxxxx&ciu_szs&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url="+ document.referrer + "&description_url=xxxxxx.com&correlator=" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sfbvhLz5/1/)**

Comment: Did you try URL encoding those quotes as `%22`?

Comment: The issue is that the jquery validation plugin is hitting the field first. How can I run `encodeURI` on the field before hitting the validation plugin?

Comment: Please, again, post enough code in the OP to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do not rely solely on the jsFiddle for this. Thank-you.

Comment: Clearly, there is more to this than quotation marks.  Remove them all and your URL is still invalid.  You cannot have a valid URL with whitespace.

Comment: @Sparky, everything in the current app is in the fiddle. It's easier to see there and functioning. The URL is valid, I have just replaced the actual URL and account ID information with "x"'s. The URL that is input into the last text area in the form is placed into a value within code which is embedded into a site. However, the regex you provided is not working.

Comment: @Matt, I have no way to know your exact URL specification, so I did not provide you with a regex.  That is simply the `url` regex you're using now, and I merely showed you the proper method for creating a custom rule.  It's up to you to provide the regex that meets your spec.  As far as your question, I'm not making the request for code out of personal preference. [Please read this page:  *"...also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Sparky, I understand its not out of personal preference. I think the simplest solution is to basically test the URL has a valid protocol `http://` or `https://`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example URL in your OP (with whitespace and quotation marks) is not valid and the `url` rule is evaluating it correctly.

> Or is there a better way with the jQuery Validate plugin?

For any situation where the built-in rule is not working for your specification, you can write your own custom rule.  Construct your new function and declare it with [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/), using the standard `url` rule as a basis.

**Simply [*adjust* this regex](http://www.regexr.com/3b4b0) according to your specification**...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myURL", function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(value);
}, 'Please enter a valid URL.');
```

Usage:

```
rules: {
    // other rules,
    adTag: {
        myURL: true
    }
}
```